# Split a string twice in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, dictionary, kotlin, filter

I have a string and I want to split it based on the & and =

kit=xxxx&accountType=xxxxx&accountId=1234

I want accountId and it's value 1234 out of it. I have tried the below approach and feel it has more time complexity.

Could you please suggest better approach?

```
            myString = "kit=xxxx&accountType=xxxxx&accountId=1234"

            val queryComponents: List<String>? = myString?.split("&")?.map { it }
            queryComponents?.forEach { element ->
                if (element.contains(key)) {
                    val search = element.split("=").map { it }
                    print("key = " + search[0] + "value = " + search[1])
                }
            }
```

Comment: In both cases, `map { it }` could just be `toList()`, but that's kind of pointless anyway since you already have an Iterable. Eliminating these won't affect your time complexity, though they will cut down on unnecessary array copies under the hood. I would look into Regex for doing this with better time complexity.

Answer (score 5):

Your approach is fine, but your code is pretty hard to read. We can split by `&` first and then by `=` which is probably the easiest to understand:

```kotlin
val accountId = myString.splitToSequence('&')
    .map { it.split('=') }
    .find { it[0] == "accountId" }
    ?.get(1)
```

Or we can split only once and then search for `=` using string utils. This could be a little faster as we don't create additional lists of strings:

```kotlin
val accountId = myString.splitToSequence('&')
    .find { it.startsWith("accountId=") }
    ?.takeLastWhile { it != '=' }
```

Note that by using `splitToSequence()` we split by `&` only until we find `accountId=`. Then we end the loop.

It could be even faster to not split at all and just search the string for `&accountId=`. Or use regular expressions. It would require to take into account multiple cases: `accountId=` is at the beginning, at the end or in the middle.

Anyway, I believe all these solutions have exactly the same time complexity of `O(n)`.

Comment: splitToSequence is giving me null value but if I try split and getting 1234.

Comment: Could you share exact code that gives you `null`? Both above solutions using `splitToSequence()` should find account id: https://pl.kotl.in/bLiT70Aoe

Comment: Sorry for some reason I am getting null in code but not in Kotlin play.

Answer (score 0):

```
val myString = "kit=xxxx&accountType=xxxxx&accountId=1234"

val components = myString
  .split("&", "=", ignoreCase = true)
  .chunked(2) { it[0] to it[1] }
  .toMap()

println(components["accountId"])
```